# Converting "unknown-8bit" charset to UTF-8

Tags: html, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm helping a friend add content to an older website thats been written in something like FrontPage. However I have a html document that's encoded with "unknown-8bit" charset. Brackets.io that I'm working in only supports UTF-8, so I can't open and re-save the document to the correct encoding.

How would I go about converting this file into UTF-8 so that I can then work with it in brackets.io?

I'm using OS X 10.10 Yosemite, so I'm a bit more limited than if I sat on Windows (Notepad++ springs to mind).

After google'ing some I've tried the following in terminal, but "unknown-8bit" is unsupported.

```
iconv -f unknown-8bit -t utf-8 filename.html > newfilename.html
```

Comment: `unknown-8it` is not so much an encoding as an indication that the encoding-detector gave up: It is relatively sure it's an 8bit-encoding (like nearly all are), but lacks indicators to determine which. Try another detector. You might even use your browser and change the encoding until it looks right.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `enca` or `chardet`, `enca` will probably be more successful.

If you know the language the document was written in, you can guess the encoding and try converting until you get the right results:

- English, French, German, Spanish... – usually Windows-1252
- Russian, Ukrainian... – usually Windows-1251
- Polish, Czech, Hungarian... – usually Windows-1250 or ISO-8859-2
- Japanese – usually Shift-JIS

and so on.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot! The language of the document is Swedish so i tried using 'ISO-8859-1'. It did successfully convert the document into UTF-8, however it converted the Swedish characters wrong. It will be quicker for me to manually edit this tho, then trying to find the right original encoding.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a [Brackets extension to convert files to UTF-8 encoding](https://github.com/Armacryss/brackets-utf8-converter) so you don't have to leave your editor. But if other tools are having trouble identifying/converting the original file's encoding, I'm guessing this extension will have the same problem.